# Odoo Qweb New Line in t-value string

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb

I try to achieve to have a new line (carriage return) in the string result, but so far, I don't get this working.

This example just ignores the '\n'.

```
<t t-set="foo" t-value="foo_A+'\n'+foo_B"/>
```

Comment: <br/> wont work?

Comment: nope, you cant use html in attribute values

Answer (score 2):

1. \n is working
2. add CSS "white-space: pre-wrap" to the element that contains this string value

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<t t-set="foo" t-value="foo_A+'&lt;br/&gt;'+foo_B"/>
```

Then, when you actually print that:

```
<t t-raw="foo"/>
```

But beware when doing this if variables come from untrusted sources, they could inject malicious code. Possibly a more secure alternative would be:

```
<t t-esc="foo_A"/><br/><t t-esc="foo_B"/>
```